# SCD type 2 implementation in Cloud Data Fusion Pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, scd2

I have requirement to apply SCD2 in my data fusion pipeline and my source data is GCS and target is BigQuery . I have created the pipeline and able to load the data into target BigQery so now I want to implement merge and update process as part of SCD2. Can you please help me as I'm new to Google cloud data fusion.

Comment: Use `BigQuery Execute` Action plugin at the end of your pipeline , have your SCD2 logic as sql statement , this should work.

Answer (score 1):

@phaneendra's approach is a possible solution. Anyhow, Data Fusion is designed to be used in a code-free visual way. If you want to take advantage of its potential, I would recommend you to use Wrangler for your data transformations. In Google's docs you can find an interesting and quick [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/targeting-campaign-pipeline) on how to use it to clean, transform, and process customer data. Then you would just have to sink the transformed data with the [BigQuery plugin](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/concepts/overview#plugin) as you are doing now.